# Нужен пример кода взаимодействий div блоков при наведение(hover)

Tags: html, css, html5

Предположим есть 4 блока div с разной высотой, и при наведение нужно что бы все блоки стали одной высоты. Или предположим что у них разная позиция в пространстве и при наведение они вставали в ряд.. Вообщем навел курсор на один блок и остальные тоже выполняют действие, на второй блок другие действие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 23.5%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .2s;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 140px;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 150px;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper:hover .item {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @stepa отметьте пожалуйста мой ответ как решение.

Comment: @stepa Мда... Ну спасибо так спасибо. )

Comment: @AndreyFedorov А можете решить без `!important`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov за спасибо? ладно, я сегодня добрый. поправил.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Кстати вместо `.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}` лучше `.wrapper { justify-content: space-between; }`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в начале не хотел flex использовать...